# WHOIS из Python - нужно узнать занят домен или свободен?

Tags: python, whois

Подскажите, как сделать запрос из Python 3, чтобы узнать свободен домен или занят?

Я пробовал вот такие способы, но они не сработали:

```
    s = 'domaim.ru'
    m = os.system("whois %s" % s)
    print(m)
    m = whois.whois(s)
    print(m)
```

Comment: [**Check whether domain is registered**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37105136/5951529). Спасибо.

Comment: какие у вас сложности с указанными решениями? "не сработали" — малоинформативно: что вы ожидали получить и что вместо этого происходит?